# Sample Dataset for Benchmarks

Tags: node.js, sample-data

I am working on my bachelor thesis and my topic is to benchmark nodejs applications. I have an I/O intensive application where I would need some sample files.

Therefore it would be great if I had a lot of small sized files, some medium files and some big files (>1gb). But they should represent real data (eg. pictures, pdfs, documents, archives, ...)

If you think that this should not be asked on stackoverflow please tell me where i can ask this.

**Do you know where I can get such sample datasets?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[English wikipedia database dumps (~12GB)](https://meta.wikimedia.org/wiki/Data_dump_torrents#enwiki)

[Sample audio and video files (~12MB - ~650MB)](https://kodi.tv/media-samples/)

[Text files of various sizes (~1KB - 114KB)](https://www.cl.cam.ac.uk/~mgk25/ucs/examples/)

[StackExchange data dumps (~1MB - ~15.4GB)](https://archive.org/details/stackexchange)